# Sending Mail using XAMPP on MAC OS

Tags: php, email

I have been trying to send mail using XAMPP on macOS but I cannot get it to work. I have not changed any settings within the backlogs or anything like that. Every-time I load the PHP in the browser through localhost there is HTTPS 500 ERROR in the browser (Can't handle this request). I got the code from the XAMPP FAQ and I have successfully installed the packages required to send mail so I cannot figure out where or what the issue is. I would highly appreciate any help. Thank you everyone!

```html
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "EMAIL ADDRESS GOES HERE";
$to = 'EMAIL ADDRESS GOES HERE';

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = 'EMAIL ADDRESS GOES HERE';
$password = '';

$subject = "test";
$body = "test";

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to,'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: Server errors can only be reliably diagnosed by looking at your server's error log directly.

Comment: Where can I find the error log?

Comment: Depends on your server configuration, they all vary slightly, but it's important to know where this is as it's the key to solving problems like this. Check the XAMPP documentation if you're not sure where to start, there's usually a default location.